# Doctrine 2 autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.3, doctrine-orm, autoload

```
$modelsClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Application\Model', __DIR__ . '/models');
$modelsClassLoader->register();
```

This will try to load `\Application\Model\User` in `my/application/models/Application/Model/User.php`.

I want it to load in `my/application/models/User.php`.

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Zend Framework? Why not just use its [resource autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html)?

Comment: Yes I am using ZF, how could I do with it ? Thanks

Comment: See here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html

Comment: Thanks, answer accepted for the ZF autoloader. Not possible with the Doctrine autoloader.